# devise + omniauth undefined method `find' for Symbol:Class error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, devise

```
 NoMethodError in Projects#index

Showing /home/dave/Documents/exercises/todo/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #18 raised:

undefined method `find' for Symbol:Class

Extracted source (around line #18):

15: 
16:   <div id="container">
17:     <div id="user_nav">
18:       <% if user_signed_in? %>
19:         Sign in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
20:         <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>
21:       <%else %>
```

why am i getting this error message?

**undefined method `find' for Symbol:Class**

im using rails 3.0.7 and devise 1.1.rc0

based on this tutorial http://media.railscasts.com/videos/236_omniauth_part_2.mov

**what a lame i just bundle installed devise 1.3.4 and changed secret_token or clear sessions db and **then up and running****

just incase some people might investigate some the cause of this problem just to let you know.

Comment: @user744617 - you can add an answer to your own question and accept it. That way the question will be closed.

Comment: by doing that, I believe you get extra SO points too